# t-sql to summarize range of dates from flat list of dates, grouped by other columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Suppose I had the following table:

```
UserId   AttributeId   DateStart
1        3             1/1/2020
1        4             1/9/2020
1        3             2/2/2020
2        3             3/5/2020
2        3             4/1/2020
2        3             5/1/2020
```

For each unique UserId/AttributeId pair, it is assumed that the DateEnd is the day prior to the next DateStart for that pair, otherwise it is null (or some default like crazy far into the future - 12/31/3000).

Applying this operation to the above table would yield:

```
UserId   AttributeId   DateStart     DateEnd
1        3             1/1/2020      2/1/2020
1        4             1/9/2020      <null>
1        3             2/2/2020      <null>
2        3             3/5/2020      3/31/2020
2        3             4/1/2020      4/30/2020
2        3             5/1/2020      <null>
```

What T-SQL, executing in SQL Server 2008 R2, would accomplish this?

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed query)

Try this please:

```
  SELECT 
  UserId,AttributeId,DateStart,Min(DateEnd)DateEnd
  FROM
  (
 
   SELECT X.UserId,X.AttributeId,X.DateStart, DATEADD(DD,-1,Y.DateStart) DateEnd
   FROM TAB X LEFT JOIN TAB Y
   ON (X.UserId=Y.UserId) AND (X.AttributeId=Y.AttributeId)
   AND   (X.DateStart<Y.DateStart) 

  )
 T
 GROUP BY UserId,AttributeId,DateStart
 ORDER BY DateStart
```

Comment: Thanks so much for posting an answer!  I think this won't work if the same UserId/AttributeId combo has 3 or more entries in the table.  I modified my question to show an example of that - please see the last row which is new.

Comment: I have changed query) Please, check it

Comment: SFun28, tell me, do you try query?))

Answer (score 0):

You are describing `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       dateadd(day, -1, lead(dateStart) over (partition by userId, attributeId order by dateStart)) as dateEnd
from t;
```

Comment: Sorry...should have stated that I need this to work in SQL 2008 R2!